# Testing for array PHP

Tags: php

I created an array below:

```
$email[] = $post[0];

$email[].= $post[2];
```

The result is:

```
$email = Array ( [JESSICA] => jessica.doe@laerdal.com )
```

I then pass it to a class constructor as so:

```
$email_user = new Email($id,$email,$subject,$heading,$messages,$keys);
```

The class looks like this:

```
class Email extends Users { 

protected $id;
public $strings;
public $user_email;
public $subject;
public $heading;
public $messages;
public $keys;

public function __construct($id,$user_email,$subject,$heading,$messages,$keys) {

parent::__construct($id);
$this->user_email = $user_email;
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->heading = $heading;
$this->messages = $messages;
$this->keys = $keys;
```

If I test to see if $this->user_email is an array using:

```
if(is_array($this->user_email)) {
   echo "TRUE";
}
```

it returns false. How come?

*** I found the issue, a conflict with variables both named $email. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$email[].=`?  You can do that?

Comment: @Rocket - I suspect you can, but it'd be the equivalent of $email[] = NULL . ?

Comment: @MarkBaker: I tested it and the `.` doesn't do anything.  It's the same as `$email[] =`.

Comment: Yes, the dot notation doees nothing.

Comment: @Rocket Same here, it just adds to the array.

Comment: @stevenpepe, are you sure that the result in the $email variable is the array you describe? You're not setting the [JESSICA] element anywhere in the example you give.

Comment: try var_dump($this->user_email) to see what is in there.

Comment: @h00ligan, yes $post[0] contains JESSICA, $post[1] contains the email address. This array returns true BEFORE I send it to the class, but FALSE in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that the use of the `.=` operator is generally used for concatinating two strings.

by saying `$email[] = somevalue`, you're essentially pushing the value arbitrarily into the array, which is totally good enough for what you're doing. You end up with:

```
$email[] = $post[0];
$email[] = $post[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public $user_email = array();
```

Remove the concatenation: `$email[].= $post[2];` `$email[] = $post[2];` is fine.